# styling <a> tag and <b> tag in text control.htmlText using css

Tags: css, apache-flex

I've got this mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:htmlText>
        <![CDATA[
            <a href="foo">link me</a><b>bold me</b>
        ]]>
        </mx:htmlText>
    </mx:Text>
</mx:Application>
```

(In reality, the html content is coming from an xml file.) I want to give the link a color. So I've got this in my css file:

```
a { color:#339900; }
```

But I get a warning: "The CSS type selector 'a' was not processed, because the type was not used in the application."

I also tried:

```
a:link { color:#339900; }
```

and the warning changes to: "CSS selector condition type is not supported: ':link'

According to the [live docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html), it seems like I should be able to do both things. What am I missing?

---

Also I'm using a font that has no bold, but I want to use the `fontThickness` property to create one. I've got it working when I apply it to an entire object or class, thus:

```
.thickenMe { fontThickness: 150; }
```

I want to apply it to the [b] tag, but I'm getting similar warnings as with the [a].

Answer (score 3):

From what you're describing, it sounds like you're trying to put styles in a stylesheet in your Flex application. **That won't work**. The stylesheets you're working in are used to style the application, not html content within the application.

If you want to render styled text in a htmlText block, follow the pattern described here:

[Flex 3 - Applying cascading style sheets](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Text_14.html)

Comment: Ah, so I have to have a separate css file for the html content. Seems like a strange choice to me, but I'll try that....

Answer (score 2):

Use StyleSheet::parseCSS to import custom CSS definition then the styleSheet property of mx:Text to attach it.

```
var ss : StyleSheet = new StyleSheet;
ss.parseCSS("a{color:#2222ff;} a:hover{text-decoration: underline;}");
tmsg.styleSheet=ss;
tmsg.htmlText="<a href=\"http://blabla.bla\">blabla.bla</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the css to the content of the htmlText object not the whole application.
There should be a "styleSheet" property or similar on the htmlText object you can set.

Comment: yeah, I accidentally left that out of my snipped code above. I've got that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

some text http://www.orf.at'>http://www.orf.at some text